# Unable to delete localStorage array item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I'm trying delete individual cart items from cart, which is saved in localStroage, so far I'm only able to delete whole array via removeitem() or clear(), but I want to delete selective item by item id. Mean while I'm getting below error if I used splice. I'm learning so let me know if I need to provide more information.

```
deleteProduct: (index) => {
            const existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartData"));
            existingEntries.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("cartData", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
        }
```

```
let cartData = window.localStorage.getItem('cartData');

const cart = {
    state: {
        cartData: cartData ? JSON.parse(cartData) : {
            foods: [],
            totalPrice: [],
            Quantities: []
        },
    },
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to check if `existingEntries` is an array before using the splice.

Comment: I checked by console.log(existingEntries), and its indeed an array.  Can you provide me with an example code which shows how I can remove an item from localStroage array by using id.

Comment: can you show the cartData in localstorage

Comment: I have added cartData info, please have a look

Comment: It's not an array (or string) so it has no splice method.  If this is real code you will also want to check that the value is set at all, the user can delete localStorage whenever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

1. cartData is a `String`, it's in `localStorage`, so it must be a `String`.
2. Parse it, it's an `Object`
3. `cartData.foods` is the array here

Code steps:

1. get `cartData` from `localStorage`
2. Parse it, you get a `JSON Object` with has a key `.food`
3. Access the key, `cartData.foods`
4. Splice it

Comment: Your code step # 3 did the trick, I wasn't using .foods to refer the key. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
const cartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartData"))
if(cartData && cartData.foods) {
    const existingEntries = cartData.foods;
    existingEntries.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("cartData", JSON.stringify(existingEntries))
}
```

Also you can update the `totalPrice` and `Quantities` before `setItem`

Comment: I tried your solution too and it working. Thanks for help

Comment: side note: this can result in an `Uncaught TypeError`if the `localStorage.getItem('cartData')` returns undefined, better separate steps and add verification

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse your array after you get it

```
deleteProduct: (index) => {
        var localStorageArray =  localStorage.getItem("cartData")
        const existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorageArray);
        existingEntries.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("cartData", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
    }
```

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but I'm getting same error as before, "existingEntries.splice is not a function"